# Correct way to define integral constant in .cpp file

Tags: c++

I have a class source file `Foo.cpp` and I need to define `IntVal` constant only for local use by class methods.

```
// Option 1
const int IntVal = 5;
// Option 2
static const int IntVal = 5;
// Option 3
namespace {
        const int IntVal = 5;
}

int Foo::GetValue()
{
        return this->value + IntVal;
}
```

Which one is preferred?

Comment: If it's supposed to belong to the class, you can make it a static class member. If it's just used for the implementation, option 3 is the modern way to represent something only used only in a single translation unit.

Comment: *constant only for local use by class methods* Inside the class, add: `constexpr static some_type some_name = some_value;`

Comment: or just `constexpr some_type some_name = some_value;`

Comment: `const` objects defined at file scope are by default `static`, so Option 1 and Option 2 are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hardcoded constants like that, I'd pretty much always go with:

```
static constexpr int kIntValue = 5;
```

If I had to bet, I'd say all of those compile to almost exactly the same code though (unless you're trying to use the number in a constexpr context) so it probably comes down to personal preference/style.